# Assign static IP via open-vm-tools when provisioning Ubuntu 18.04 on vSphere with Ansible

Tags: virtualization, vmware, 18.04

I'm hoping someone can provide some advice on how to use `open-vm-tools` to assign a static IP to a Ubuntu 18.04 VM being provisioned to vSphere using Ansible. I'm currently having 2 problems:

1. Networks are not being connected when the VM starts.
2. After manually connecting the networks, static IP's are not being assigned.

I've done some reading and come across various possible issues, such as `perl` not being installed and needing to install `open-vm-tools-deploypkg` but these see like outdated resolutions. My VM template has `vmware-toolbox-cmd -v 10.2.0.1608` which is above `9.10` so no requirement for `-deploypkg` and `perl` is installed (if it's even still a dependency).

I'm not sure what the root of the problem is, i.e. whether it's a bug in the Ansible `vmware_guest` module, an issue with `pyvmomi` or a vSphere problem. However, it occurred to me that it could also be an `open-vm-tools` issue but I don't know enough about how it interacts with the underlying OS to rule it in or out.

Whilst Ubuntu 18.04 is still in beta, it is only a couple of weeks away from general release. As such, I wouldn't necessarily expect the VMWare supported guest OS page to include it (it currently doesn't). What would be useful to know is if anyone else has had these 2 problems and found a way to make them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Ubuntu 18.04 isn't supported yet. 16.04, works fine. I guess I'll have to wait.